# htacces index.php?id=value to /value.html

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I got 2 urls that i want to change with htaccess should be easy but Im having a hard time with it:

`index.php?id=Agenda` to `/agenda.html`
and
`?id=Agenda` also to `/agenda.html`

Ive tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ index.php?id=$1  [L,NC]
```

and some variations on it but I cant get it to work any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=(.+?)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.html? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)\.html$ ?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Sorry made a mistake in my question i ment for more then one url: 
so Agenda is here one of the values that needs to be changed example: index.php?id=value But for Agenda this works :)

Comment: This worked like a charm :) what was wrong with my code? (I want to learn from my mistakes ;).  Also how do I add a %2(space) into the code for example ?id=room%201 ?

Comment: Your rule didn't have `.html` in the regex pattern Also as you can see you needed 2 rules not one. To allow space both rules will change (see updated one) but please don't add new problems in comments. Always better to start a new question.

Comment: Oke thanks will remember that for next time :) Ty So much for your advice and help!